# Is it possible to create/deploy a google web app with a service account as its owner?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, service-accounts

Google Apps Script project (more about this [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web))

- Create script at script.new
- Menu Publish -> deploy as a web app
- Here you choose performed by me, user, etc. Accessed by ...
- Is it possible to make it work with a service account as its owner? (so that it survives when you terminate the user's accounts later)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check out this awesome article stepping through the step-by-step approach to allow Google Apps Script to use a service account. This might work for your needs.

[How to use GCP service accounts with Google Apps Script projects](https://daubejb.medium.com/how-to-use-gcp-service-accounts-with-google-apps-script-projects-to-automate-actions-in-g-suite-7020a520bef7)

One thing to note is that the Google Apps Script API itself does not work with service accounts. As per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/concepts).

Hope this helps! Let me know if you need further assistance :)

Comment: It would then only be possible to create a web app with an existing user account (not with a service account), thanks!